# How to reload a JSP with request.getAttribute values

Tags: java, struts, httprequest

I have this application where i want to populate a text file on the basis of entries entered from user interface. 
I chose Struts1 for this and i have been able to complete most of the functionalities.But the part of keeping on populating the 
text file on the basis of user entries in my JSP is something i am struggling with. The following are the flow of pages on user interface

1.'Accept user entries' http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1178-104.html 
2.'Ask for scan data on the basis of entries in page1' http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1178-105.html 
3.'Submit after entering the scandata. ' http://www.image-share.com/ijpg-1178-106.html 
(I have been able to straighten the null values in the images via session variables. Thanks to Dave) 
message is seen with null entries like this Post validation. 
My questions is: 
 What should be used so that there is a scenario that the users enter the Scan Data on page 2 and can continue to enter 
more scan data values by falling back on the same JSP . I was thinking on the lines of reloading the page using JavaScript 
on the button click. Is it the right approach?

The relevant code for this is

```
 <html:form action="txtwriter">    
  <% String itemname = (String)session.getAttribute("itemname");   %> 
 <% String lotnumber = (String)session.getAttribute("lotnumber");   %>
 <% String godownname = (String)session.getAttribute("godownname");  %> 
 <br/>  
 <% String message = (String)session.getAttribute("message");    
 session.setAttribute( "theFileName", message );  %>  
  Filename : <%= message %>  
 <br/>  Item Name :<%= itemname %>
  <br/> Lot Number :<%= lotnumber %> 
   <br/>    Godown Name :<%= godownname %>  
 <br/>    <bean:message key="label.scandata"/> 
 <html:text property="scanData" ></html:text>    
 <html:errors property="scanData"/> 
 <br/>     
<html:submit/> 
  /* How should the submit button handle the onClick event so that when the users click  
  after entering the text.
 1. The entered text must be populated in the text file using a different action class.  (I have    this part working) 
  2.They must be on the same jsp with the scanData text box cleared waiting for the next  user      entry into that text 
 box so that this subsequest entry can also be entered into the text file. 
 Is there a way i can empty the 'scanData' textbox by accessing it by name inside my action so that i can empty it from my action class?
 (I am looking for this     answer)
```

*/

I used this inside the LoginAction.java

```
HttpSession session = request.getSession();   
session.setAttribute("message", textFile);   
session.setAttribute("itemname",loginForm.getItemName().trim());   
session.setAttribute("lotnumber",loginForm.getLotNumber().trim());    
session.setAttribute("godownname",loginForm.getStockGodown().trim());
```

Comment: `TextWriter.java` is not an action class, it's a form; it's unclear how it's related.

Comment: Honestly, it's pretty difficult to get through all this, and it's not entirely clear to me what the root issue is.

Comment: @DaveNewton Thank you Dave for pointing out it was my mistake sorry. I have added the correct action class now. I hope you can corellate now seeing the screen prints i have provided .Please direct me as to what you need for a clearer question.

Comment: A clearer, more concise restatement of the problem. If you're losing form values, keep them in the session, or re-set them properly. The form itself can be in the session, via configuration.

Comment: @DaveNewton : I have been able to solve one of the issues with session attribute and i have streamlined my question too. Would like to have your advice on this. Thanks.

Comment: I don't see any changes.

Comment: @DaveNewton : Sorry i saw something like my edit needed to be peer reviwed..anyways i have updated my question now

Answer (score 0):

(Not an answer; refactored but untested code for others trying to help.)

This is a refactored action, making it easier to see what's actually going on; the original code is difficult to reason about. The `trim()` functionality is moved to action form setters to avoid redundancy.

```
public class LoginAction extends Action {

    public ActionForward execute(ActionMapping mapping, ActionForm form, HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws Exception {
        LoginForm loginForm = (LoginForm) form;
        if (invalidForm(loginForm)) {
            return mapping.findForward("failure");
        }

        String fileName = createFile(loginForm);

        request.setAttribute("message", fileName);
        request.setAttribute("itemname", loginForm.getItemName());
        request.setAttribute("lotnumber", loginForm.getLotNumber());
        request.setAttribute("godownname", loginForm.getStockGodown());

        return mapping.findForward("success");
    }

    private String createFile(LoginForm loginForm) throws IOException {
        ServletContext context = getServlet().getServletContext();
        String driveName = context.getInitParameter("drive").trim();
        String folderName = context.getInitParameter("foldername").trim();

        String pathName = driveName + ":/" + folderName;
        new File(pathName).mkdirs();

        String fileNamePath = pathName + createFileName(loginForm);
        ensureFileExists(fileNamePath);

        return fileNamePath;
    }

    private void ensureFileExists(String fileNamePath) throws IOException {
        boolean fileExists = new File(fileNamePath).exists();
        if (!fileExists) {
            File file = new File(fileNamePath);
            file.createNewFile();
        }
    }

    private boolean invalidForm(LoginForm loginForm) {
        return loginForm.getItemName().equals("")
                || loginForm.getLotNumber().equals("")
                || loginForm.getStockGodown().equals("");
    }

    private String createFileName(LoginForm loginForm) {
        return loginForm.getItemName() + "_"
                + loginForm.getLotNumber() + "_"
                + loginForm.getStockGodown() + "_"
                + createFileNameTimeStamp() + ".txt";
    }

    private String createFileNameTimeStamp() {
        SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy.MM.dd G 'at' hh.mm.ss z");
        String dateTime = sdf.format(Calendar.getInstance().getTime());
        String[] tempDateStore = dateTime.split("AD at");
        return tempDateStore[0].trim() + "_" + tempDateStore[1].trim();
    }

}
```